# In ggplot2/plotly ,when I use `geom_bar(stat='identity',position='fill')`,how to change number tip to percent format

Tags: ggplot2, plotly, ggplotly

In R/ggplot2 ,when I use `geom_bar(stat='identity',position='fill')`,
the 'sales' tip show '0.80000',how to change it to '80.0%' ?
(I know mutate a new variable use `scales::percent(sales)`,can work in `geom_point`)

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
test_data <- data.frame(category=c('A','B','A','B'),
                        sub_category=c('a1','b1','a2','b2'),
                        sales=c(1,2,4,5))

p <- test_data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=category,y=sales,
                              fill=sub_category))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position='fill') 

ggplotly(p)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option (and perhaps the easiest one) would be to compute your percentages manually instead of making use of `position = "fill"` and create the tooltip manually via the `text` aesthetic which makes it easy to style the numbers, ... as you like:

```
library(plotly)

test_data <- data.frame(
  category = c("A", "B", "A", "B"),
  sub_category = c("a1", "b1", "a2", "b2"),
  sales = c(1, 2, 4, 5)
)

test_data <- test_data %>%
  group_by(category) %>%
  mutate(pct = sales / sum(sales))

p <- test_data %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = category, y = pct, fill = sub_category)) +
  geom_col(aes(text = paste0(
    "category: ", category, "<br>",
    "sub_category: ", sub_category, "<br>",
    "sales: ", scales::percent(pct)
  )))

ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

[image]